# how to use an string as GUID type in php?

Tags: php, web-services, guid

I have a **guid code** as **string type**; and i need to use it as **guid type**!

My code is :

```
$soapClient = new nusoap_client('https://test1.test/test2.asmx');
$soapClient->xml_encoding = "UTF-8";
$soapClient->soap_defencoding = "UTF-8";
$soapClient->decode_utf8 = false;

// test guid_code :
$guid_code = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
$result = $soapClient->call('sample_function',array('guid_code'=>(GUID)$guid_code));
print_r($result);
exit;
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: There is not way, and no need to cast that string to `(GUID)` if you look at the error it seems to be saying it does not like the `detail` parameter. Its not complaining about the `'guid_code'` at all.

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly.
yes it is the other error.

Comment: Are you sure the guid has to be a GUID object? PHP doesn't have a guid type. Is this a class you are including? I would fix the error you are receiving before trying to fix other parts.